# Multiple if any command in spss

Tags: spss

Is it possible to use Nested if any command in spss?
for example

```
 if any(1, a to c) and if (1, s to x) xx=1.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, but your syntax isn't quite right.
if (any(1, a to c) and any(1, s to x)) xx=1.

The if expression can be arbitrarily complicated, but it needs to be an expression.  The if part is a statement.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Just to provide an answer that clarifies the *nested* part, here's an example using `do if` instead of `if`.

```
do if any(1, a to c).
    do if any(1, s to x).
        compute xx=1.
    end if.
end if.
```

This code finds rows with at least one time a score of 1 on any of the variables `a` to `c`. Only among these rows, it finds rows with at least one time a score of 1 on any of the variables `s` to `x`. The rows that pass the first statement and subsequently pass the second statement are assigned `xx=1`.

It yields the same results as:

`if any(1, a to c)`**`and`**`any(1, s to x) xx=1.`

However, the following yields different results:

```
if any(1, a to c) xx=1.
if any(1, s to x) xx=1.
```

This essentially means the same as using **or** between 2 conditional statements

`if any(1, a to x)`**`or`**`any(1, s to x) xx=1.`